# Switching lines in preamble causes error/NO error

Tags: incompatibility, package-options, compilation-error

I have 2 almost idenctical lines of LaTeX source.
They differ only in switching order of these two lines

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
```

One causes error and the other one compiles. WHY?

NO ERROR:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text

\index{Apple}\index{Apricot}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

ERROR:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}


\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text

\index{Apple}\index{Apricot}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The second source causes this error:

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "ideje10"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: ideje10.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file ideje10.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ideje10.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ideje10.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   makeindex.exe "ideje10.idx"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./ideje10.mst...done (3 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file ideje10.idx....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).
Generating output file ideje10.ind....done (7 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in ideje10.ind.
Transcript written in ideje10.ilg.


Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\ideje10.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/TH0dipl/ideje10.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package amsmath.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 

? 

! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.6
```

Process has been killed ...

===========================================
I can of course switch the lines to get a compiling code, but I'm curious why this happens.

Comment: You should not load the same package multiple times, especially not with different options.

Comment: In the second code, you first load amsmath without any option, then you load it with an option. Never do that! Also, why  loading a package twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation of `\usepackage` in [`source2e.pdf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e):

> `\usepackage[⟨package-option-list ⟩]{⟨package-list ⟩}[⟨version ⟩]`
>
> There
>   can be any number of these declarations. All packages in
>   ⟨package-list⟩ are called with the same options. [...]
>
> Each
>   package is loaded only once. If the same package is requested more
>   than once, nothing happens, unless the package has been requested with
>   options that were not given the first time it was loaded, in which
>   case an error is produced.

In your second example you load `amsmath` with the option `fleqn` that was not given the first time, so you get an error ("option clash").  In general each package should only be loaded once.